# How to find duplicate values and corresponding value into new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have data frame like this where country and name where ever it is unique for same ID have to be in new columns.

[image]

Expected output : 
If the value is repeating that need not be displayed in the new columns, it can be blank

[image]

Tried with below code, but is working fine for one column what if i have 2 columns together and do the same task.

```
group = df.groupby('ID')
df1 = group.apply(lambda x:x['COUNTRY'].unique())
df1=df1.apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following,

```
# Create a dataframe where each element is aggregated as list
new_df = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: pd.Series(x).unique().tolist())

# Generate column names to be used after expanding lists
country_cols = ['Country_'+str(i) for i in range(new_df["Country"].str.len().max())]
name_cols = ['Name_'+str(i) for i in range(new_df["Name"].str.len().max())]

# Drop the Country, Name columns from the original and expand Country, Name columns and concat that to the original dataframe, finally do a fillna
df2 = pd.concat(
    [new_df.drop(['Country','Name'], axis=1), 
     pd.DataFrame.from_records(new_df["Country"], columns=country_cols, index=new_df.index),
     pd.DataFrame.from_records(new_df["Name"], columns=name_cols, index=new_df.index)
     ], axis=1
     ).fillna(' ')
```

Comment: I got an error as below.
TypeError: Argument 'rows' has incorrect type (expected list, got Series)

Comment: @Karthike Can you tell me which line you got the error in?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with a simple function :

```
def unique_column_unstack(dataframe,agg_columns):
    dfs = []
    for col in agg_columns:
        agg_df = df.groupby('ID')[col].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.unique().tolist())).unstack()        
        agg_df.columns = agg_df.columns.map(lambda x : f"{col}_{x+1}")
        dfs.append(agg_df)
    return pd.concat(dfs,axis=1)
```

---

```
new_df = unique_column_unstack(df,['COUNTRY','NAME'])

print(new_df)

       COUNTRY_1 COUNTRY_2 NAME_1 NAME_2
ID                                      
20_001        US        IN    LIZ    LAK
20_002        US       NaN    LIZ   CHRI
20_003        US        EU    LIZ    NaN
20_004        EU       NaN   CHRI    NaN
```

Comment: @Karthike no problem, please green tick this answer if it solved your problem so it can be closed.